# Can i restrict my service from running as root?

Tags: linux, root, systemd, user-permissions

I am running my service as a user (given the correct permissions and added to appropriate groups), but if I want, I can also run it as root.
How can I disable this system-wide and not for a single application?

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: We can't *prevent* root running a program, but we can add code to rectify the situation as soon as we reach user code.  The easiest way in C is to call one of the `setuid()` family of calls to change to (e.g.) the "nobody" user.  If the process isn't sufficiently privileged, the `setuid` will fail (we can ignore the error return from it), but if it's run as root, it will no longer be doing so.

Comment: Is there any setting to set this globally on the system instead of programming it on the application itself?

Comment: That would be a [sf] or [unix.se] question (but I think the answer is no).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming its written in bash. you can do something like this:

```
if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Cant run this as root" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Another way to detect which user is running the script is

```
id -u
$UID
```

Im currently in my Mac Box and logged as root in a terminal this is the output

```
  ~# id -u
0
~# echo $UID
0
~# echo $EUID
0
~#
~#
```

So you are basically saying if my check on the user id is 0 then its root. So just print a message and exit